# What is special about Perl function($$) form?

Tags: perl

I have inherited functions of the form:

```
sub func($$) {

}
```

I am more used to seeing:

```
sub func {
  ## then extract params using shift for example
}
```

I looked up `$$` and it is a means to get the current Process ID.  But looking at the function it doesn't look like the Process ID is used here.  so does `$$` mean something else in this context?

The function I am puzzled about is parseMessage below.  Why the `($$)`?

```
use FileHandle;

# The structure of function is pretty much like this - names changed only
sub parseMessage($$)
{
  my $string = shift;
  my $fileHandle = shift;

  my $Message = undef;

  # parseAMessage and parseBMessage are functions to extract specific types of messages from file
  if ( ($Message = parseAMessage($string, $fileHandle))
    || ($Message = parseBMessage($string, $fileHandle)) )
  {

  }

  return $Message;
}


sub parseAMessage($$)
{
}

sub parseBMessage($$)
{
}

# The function seems to use arguments arg1: string from file, arg2: filehandle of file
# presumably idea behind this is to process current line in file but also have access to file
# handle to move to next line where required. So the way I am calling this is probably not
# great Perl - I am a beginner perler
$fh = FileHandle->new;
    if ($fh->open("< myfile.log")) {
        # here we evaluate the file handle in a scalar context to get next line
        while($line = <$fh>) {
            parseMessage($line, $fh);   
            #print <$fh>;
        }

        $fh->close;
    }
    print "DONE\n";
1;
```

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/297034/1030675

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are prototypes and define what the function takes as arguments (not safely..).

It allows you do define functions like the built in functions so you could call your `sub doSomething` like you call `print`.

`doSomething($scalar)` or `doSomething $scalar` would produce the same result, like `print($scalar)` vs. `print $scalar`

As per comments above: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes

Comment: `print` is probably not a very good example, since it has no special argument parsing, except for the fact that `print` without arguments works like `print $_`. (If you really want that for your own function, you can achieve it with a prototype of `(_@)`.) Something like emulating `push` would be a more interesting example (and, in fact, that's what the perlsub section you linked to uses).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen you are probably right but it was the first to come to mind, didn't want to overcomplicate with map/grep/array functions

Comment: Actually `print` has pretty special argument parsing because of the `print $fh @list` and `print {$fh} @list` forms, and this cannot be emulated with prototypes. [See also this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26368555/subroutines-that-take-an-optional-block-parameter).

Comment: @tobyink: That's just [indirect object syntax](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlobj.html#Indirect-Object-Syntax), though.